# Filter a list of data frames based on the first value in a column

Tags: r

I have some data, example here:

```
 dat1 <- data.frame(a = c("5","10","15","20"), b = c("0.1","0.2","0.3","0.4"))
 dat2 <- data.frame(a = c("15","20","25","30"), b = c("0.5","0.6","0.7","0.8"))
 datalist <-list (dat1,dat2)
```

Giving me a format like this

```
    [[1]]
   a   b
1  5 0.1
2 10 0.2
3 15 0.3
4 20 0.4

   [[2]]
   a   b
1 15 0.5
2 20 0.6
3 25 0.7
4 30 0.8
```

I want to be able to filter the list of data frames with the condition that the first value of column `a` should be `<= 10`. So in this scenario the output would be just the first data frame [[1]], and the second data frame would be ignored entirely.

Desired output

```
    [[1]]
   a   b
1  5 0.1
2 10 0.2
3 15 0.3
4 20 0.4
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I have an answer for you, `Filter`, but theres a few questions. Those are factors or characters in your example. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to get a vector of logicals indicating whether each element of a list meets a certain condition. This can then be applied to subset the list in the usual way with `[`. E.g:

```
datalist[sapply(datalist, function(x){as.numeric(x[[1,"a"]]) <= 10})]
```

will return only the first element in your example.

(Note the `as.numeric` is necessary because your numbers are stored as character strings here)

Comment: Great thanks, I had thought of using sapply but wasn't sure on the indexing.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `keep` function from `purrr`. It takes a predicate function `.p` and apply it on every element of a list and return those elements that predicate function equals to a single `TRUE`.

```
lirbary(purrr)

datalist %>%
  keep(~ .x[["a"]][1] %>% as.numeric() <= 10)

[[1]]
   a   b
1  5 0.1
2 10 0.2
3 15 0.3
4 20 0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(\(x) as.numeric(x$a[1]) <= 10, datalist)
[[1]]
   a   b
1  5 0.1
2 10 0.2
3 15 0.3
4 20 0.4
```